# spring-web JAR mysteriously deleted when running as web application

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I've a Maven-based project using Google App Engine 1.8.3. From the command line it compiles and starts the local server without any problems.

However, if I try to use `Run As` -> `Web Application`, I have a `ClassNotFoundException` for

```
org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletRequestHandledEvent
```

This class is inside `spring-web` JAR, which is added as a dependency in my `pom.xml`. The really strange behaviour is shown when watching the `lib` directory of the exploded war:

```
watch "ls -lh target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/ | grep web"
```

that is, when I compile from the command line, `spring-web` JAR is there together with `spring-webmvc` JAR, but when I use `Run As`, `Web Application`, `spring-web` JAR is deleted.

This behaviour leaves me puzzled, any ideas?

Comment: This may sound really silly.. But have you tried refreshing your application and then running it.. ? Try the steps --> 1.) Maven Clean --> 2.)Maven Build --> 3.)Refresh the project --> Run on local server.

Comment: Are you using GWT by any chance?

Comment: @user2339071 Tried refreshing/cleaning/rebuilding, same error.

Comment: @chrylis I'm not using GWT

Comment: Can you show the dependency in pom.xml. ?

Comment: @user2339071 see -> [pom.xml](https://github.com/stivlo/gae/blob/master/pom.xml), dependency `spring-web`

Comment: Just to test the application can you include `spring-webmvc` jar directly in you `lib` folder and see if it works.?

Comment: if it wouldn't then that's a question.

Comment: @user2339071, randomly, sometimes it reloaded correctly, other times it complained that my entity class is not enhanced by datanucleus.

Comment: @stivlo: As per your `pom.xml` you seem to have an older version of Maven plugin. Try updating that first. Secondly, if you are using Eclipse IDE for your project, it's better to add `springnature` and to your project and use `springbuilder` in `<buildcommand>` . Although I only use `springwebmvc` in my pom and skip `springweb` altogether, I guess for you that might not be an option. Would it.?

Comment: @user2339071: updated maven-compiler-plugin to version 3.1, maven-war-plugin to version 2.4, added maven-eclipse-plugin 2.9 with org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature and com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.gaeNature -- problem persists, but it doesn't lose run as web application when I update the maven project, which is good.

Comment: Seems like we are heading in the right direction. Try removing `spring-web` dependency and keep the `springwebmvc` dependency. Check if problem persists.

Comment: Same error, I don't know how to do without spring-web, since it's needed for `ContextLoaderListener`, which sets up the whole environment

Comment: One last suggestion, try the following configuration on your maven-plugin:                 `<configuration>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>`